# "The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame" error for non-sysadmin users

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, navigation

I have a button that calls a Visualforce page that invokes an Aura app/component via Lightning out. I need to do this because in Lightning we cannot have Actions on list views.

Anyway, for me - sysadmin - it works perfectly. At some point the following Javascript code is executed:

```
window.parent.location.href = '/lightning/r/Verkoopkans_per_mail__c/' + objectId + '/view';
```

For me this works. Other users get this error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
>   $A.getCallback() [Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The
>   current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame
>   to '/lightning/r/Verkoopkans_per_mail__c/a0r3M00000006gTQAQ/view'.]
>   Callback failed:
>   apex://OpportunityForLWCController/ACTION$getAvailableOppPerMail
>   Failing descriptor: {markup://c:GetOppPerMailWrapper}

When I google for 'The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to' I get results for not Salesforce specific same-origin-policy problems. But then it should happen to me as well, right? Those kinds of problems don't depend on profiles/permissions?

The custom object Verkoopkans_per_mail__c + its instance is accessible to other users, they can access it via another route and they have sufficient permissions to view it.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because in `OpportunityForLWCController.cls` your method `getAvailableOppPerMail()` is throwing some error for non-sysadmin users. Most likely due to failing CRUD/FLS checks. Therefore, the Lightning service responsible for navigation refuses to navigate to the failing page.

Also, if you are embedding a VisualForce page under Lightning Experience, then you should use `sforce.one.navigateToSObject(objectId)` instead of assigning to `window.parent.location.href` as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_prepare_vf_window.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank for for pointing this out to me, I have corrected my code. Though I do not think it is the cause of the error. It reeks like a permission problem and it might have to do with caching. Just before the navigation, the owner of the object is changed to the current user.While testing, I have seen once that after navigation, the owner was not changed yet. I refreshed the page and the owner was changed. This could explain the problem that a non-sysadmin user experiences.

Comment: @SanderdeJong ah, now I get it. Adjusted my answer per your comment.

Comment: @SanderdeJong can you add the reference code from OpportunityForLWCController.getAvailableOppPerMail() ?

Answer (score 0):

When in lightning I have found that errors can happen with calling new visualforce due to the object id not being available for the new page (that is launching) The new visualforce is relying on that Id being there in the URL. Lightning can have issues with this depending on the context of from where you are launching the new visualforce.

Troubleshoot 1 - Look in the URL area when you get the error.  Do you see the object ID in the URL?

Also check - If this is happening in a community then ensure that the page you are calling is also allowed to be in the community.